# Getting a long list of specific elements from a list of indexes and column coordinates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing, processing-efficiency

```
data=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[21,23,24],[31,32,33]])

i=[0,1,2] # this is same as the index

y=[1,2,0]
```

data.iloc[x,y] gives me a 3x3 df, which I do not need.

I need to run this on a large df and would like to get the ELEMENTS (1,1) , (2,2) , (3,0) of the dataframe: 2, 24,31 .
So I'd like to have the most efficient solution. I can obviously use a for loop with iterrows or even something like:
`data.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[y[int(x.name)]],axis=1).values`

Is the for/apply already the fastest solution?

Isn't there a more direct way of getting only the elements, not a slice, of a df when you have a list(/series/df) with index,column coordinates?

Thanks

Comment: One approach is to use `data.to_numpy()[x,y]`. I'm not sure how efficient this would be

Comment: Indeed, the documentation seems to [recommend something similar](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.
Indeed, with a 50k rows df (so not so big) the apply version takes 1.2 s, the numpy version 0.01 s. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels), it seem that `data.to_numpy()[x,y]` is a reasonable approach.